# Programmatic way to set profile attributes

Tags: profile

I have a requirment to remove "Modify All", "Edit" , "Delete" permissions on a custom object for a quite large list of profiles.

Rather than going to **each** of these profiles and making the profile changes via UI is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Enhanced Profile List Views to update object permissions directly in the profile list view.

1. Setup --> User Interface --> Mark "Enable Enhanced Profile List View" TRUE
2. Setup --> Profiles --> Create a custom list view for your custom profiles and add the object permissions to your columns.
3. Check off all the ones you want to edit
4. Use the inline editing to mark permissions true and false
5. Select "All XX selected records" under "Apply changes to"

Hope this helps!

[image: Profile List View]

[image: Edit Permissions in List View]

Answer (score 1):

In a apex this is not possible. 
You can achieve this using ant or any other type of deployment.

In order to save time and make things automated you can take profile metadata refresh.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <objectPermissions>
        <allowCreate>true</allowCreate>
        <allowDelete>true</allowDelete>
        <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
        <allowRead>true</allowRead>
        <modifyAllRecords>true</modifyAllRecords>
        <object>Application__c</object>
        <viewAllRecords>true</viewAllRecords>
    </objectPermissions>
</Profile>
```

Object Permission looks like above. Now you can create multiple profiles with this configuration and deploy them at once.

Answer (score 1):

The [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/) provides programmatic access from any web-service capable language including [Apex itself](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). So if this is a modification that you want to repeat in the future it could be worth writing some code.

But a more common approach would be to read/modify/write the profiles using one of the IDEs or the [Ant tools](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/) where you would use a few search and replace operations across all the files for the "modify" part.